# (Python/Scrapy/Splash) Spider suddenly started printing empty results

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapy-splash

System: Windows 10, Python 2.7.15, Scrapy 1.5.1

Goal: Retrieve text from within html markup for each of the link items on the target website, including those revealed (6 at a time) via the '+ SEE MORE ARCHIVES' button.

Target Website: https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info

Spider was working as intended during the design phase, right up until I put in the loop that would have it scrape the entire scope of desired pages. I'm not sure what/if I changed that would have broken it, so I'm coming here to see if anyone can spot anything. Splash is installed, not entirely sure if it is a dependency for this. Latest Python 2.7 on a Windows 10 machine.

Code:

```
import json
import scrapy

ajaxrequest = 'https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset=6'

class WebURLItem(scrapy.Item):
    href = scrapy.Field()
    eventtype = scrapy.Field()
    eventmonth = scrapy.Field()
    eventdate = scrapy.Field()
    eventyear = scrapy.Field()

class MTGODailyURLSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "thing"
    download_delay = 1.5
    concurrent_requests = 1
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        #'Cookie': '', #Not really sure if I need to include this
        'Host': 'magic.wizards.com',
        'Referer': 'https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36',
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 6,
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ["MTGOURL", "EventType", "EventMonth", "EventDate", "EventYear"],
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.initparse)

    def initparse(self, response):
        for event in response.css('div.article-item-extended'):
            yield {
                'href': event.css('a::attr(href)').extract(),
                'eventtype': event.css('h3::text').extract(),
                'eventmonth': event.css('span.month::text').extract(),
                'eventdate': event.css('span.day::text').extract(),
                'eventyear': event.css('span.year::text').extract(),
            }
            yield scrapy.Request('https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset=6', headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        for event in jsonresponse['data']:
            selector = scrapy.Selector(text=event, type='html')
            item = WebURLItem()
            item['href'] = selector.css('a::attr(href)').extract()
            item['eventtype'] = selector.css('h3::text').extract()
            item['eventmonth'] = selector.css('span.month::text').extract()
            item['eventdate'] = selector.css('span.day::text').extract()
            item['eventyear'] = selector.css('span.year::text').extract()
            yield item
        #if jsonresponse['displaySeeMore']:
        #    nextindex = jsonresponse['offset']
        #    yield scrapy.Request('https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset={0}'.format(nextindex), headers=self.headers, callback=self.parse)
```

Log:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Justin\Google Drive\Magic the Gathering\DB Resources\Webscraping\Crawler - MTGODailyResults> scrapy crawl thing -o attempt.csv
2018-09-23 06:11:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: MTGODailyResults)
2018-09-23 06:11:33 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.0, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.7.0, Python 2.7.15 (v2.7.15:ca079a3ea3, Apr 30 2018, 16:30:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.0i  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134
2018-09-23 06:11:33 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'MTGODailyResults.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'attempt.csv', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1, 'BOT_NAME': 'MTGODailyResults', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['MTGODailyResults.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['MTGOURL', 'EventType', 'EventMonth', 'EventDate', 'EventYear'], 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 6}
2018-09-23 06:11:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2018-09-23 06:11:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-09-23 06:11:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-09-23 06:11:34 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-09-23 06:11:34 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-09-23 06:11:34 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-09-23 06:11:34 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-09-23 06:11:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://magic.wizards.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-09-23 06:11:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info> (referer: None)
2018-09-23 06:11:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info>
{'eventmonth': [u' September '], 'eventtype': [u'Competitive Legacy Constructed League'], 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '], 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/competitive-legacy-constructed-league-2018-09-22'], 'eventdate': [u'22']}
2018-09-23 06:11:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info>
{'eventmonth': [u' September '], 'eventtype': [u'Competitive Modern Constructed League'], 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '], 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/competitive-modern-constructed-league-2018-09-21'], 'eventdate': [u'21']}
2018-09-23 06:11:37 [scrapy.dupefilters] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset=6> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
2018-09-23 06:11:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info>
{'eventmonth': [u' September '], 'eventtype': [u'Competitive Standard Constructed League'], 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '], 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/competitive-standard-constructed-league-2018-09-20'], 'eventdate': [u'20']}
2018-09-23 06:11:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info>
{'eventmonth': [u' September '], 'eventtype': [u'Pauper Constructed League'], 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '], 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/pauper-constructed-league-2018-09-19'], 'eventdate': [u'19']}
2018-09-23 06:11:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info>
{'eventmonth': [u' September '], 'eventtype': [u'Competitive Modern Constructed League'], 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '], 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/competitive-modern-constructed-league-2018-09-18'], 'eventdate': [u'18']}
2018-09-23 06:11:37 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info>
{'eventmonth': [u' September '], 'eventtype': [u'Pauper Challenge'], 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '], 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/pauper-challenge-2018-09-17'], 'eventdate': [u'17']}
2018-09-23 06:11:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset=6> (referer: https://magic.wizards.com/en/content/deck-lists-magic-online-products-game-info)
2018-09-23 06:11:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset=6>
{'eventdate': [u'17'],
 'eventmonth': [u' September '],
 'eventtype': [u'Modern PTQ'],
 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '],
 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/modern-ptq-2018-09-17']}
2018-09-23 06:11:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset=6>
{'eventdate': [u'17'],
 'eventmonth': [u' September '],
 'eventtype': [u'Legacy Challenge'],
 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '],
 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/legacy-challenge-2018-09-17']}
2018-09-23 06:11:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset=6>
{'eventdate': [u'17'],
 'eventmonth': [u' September '],
 'eventtype': [u'Competitive Standard Constructed League'],
 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '],
 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/competitive-standard-constructed-league-2018-09-17']}
2018-09-23 06:11:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset=6>
{'eventdate': [u'16'],
 'eventmonth': [u' September '],
 'eventtype': [u'Brawl League'],
 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '],
 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/brawl-league-2018-09-16']}
2018-09-23 06:11:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset=6>
{'eventdate': [u'16'],
 'eventmonth': [u' September '],
 'eventtype': [u'Vintage Challenge'],
 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '],
 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/vintage-challenge-2018-09-16']}
2018-09-23 06:11:39 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://magic.wizards.com/en/section-articles-see-more-ajax?l=en&f=9041&search-result-theme=&limit=6&fromDate=&toDate=&event_format=0&sort=DESC&word=&offset=6>
{'eventdate': [u'16'],
 'eventmonth': [u' September '],
 'eventtype': [u'Standard PTQ'],
 'eventyear': [u' 2018 '],
 'href': [u'/en/articles/archive/mtgo-standings/standard-ptq-2018-09-16']}
2018-09-23 06:11:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-09-23 06:11:39 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (12 items) in: attempt.csv
2018-09-23 06:11:39 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1097,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 85479,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 5,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 23, 10, 11, 39, 111000),
 'item_scraped_count': 12,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 17,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 23, 10, 11, 34, 452000)}
2018-09-23 06:11:39 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
PS C:\Users\Justin\Google Drive\Magic the Gathering\DB Resources\Webscraping\Crawler - MTGODailyResults>
```

Output:

```
MTGOURL,EventType,EventMonth,EventDate,EventYear
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
,,,,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the fields you're specifying for export exist in your data.

`'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ["MTGOURL", "EventType", "EventMonth", "EventDate", "EventYear"]`

vs

```
class WebURLItem(scrapy.Item):
    href = scrapy.Field()
    eventtype = scrapy.Field()
    eventmonth = scrapy.Field()
    eventdate = scrapy.Field()
    eventyear = scrapy.Field()
```

The field names in the export definition need to match the property names on the item.

Change your export fields like this:

`'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ["href", "eventtype", "eventmonth", "eventdate", "eventyear"]`